# How to Query against a List field and return a Page with Spring Data Hazelcast?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, hazelcast

I have a Spring Boot project using [spring-data-hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast) 2.4.0. It is a really nice library providing HazelcastRepository which abstracts hazelcast interactions behind the standard Spring Data Repository paradigm. But I've run into the below problem when trying to do a pageable query against a list field in my object:

I have this object:

```java
@Data
@KeySpace
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String author;
    private List<String> categories;

}
```

I'd like to perform a Pageable query against the list field using HazelcastRepository. I can query within the list using the org.springframework.data.hazelcast.repository.query.Query annotation below and it works fine:

```java
@Query("categories[any] = %s")
Iterable<Book> findByCategory(String category);
```

But when I try to return a Page with this method:

```java
@Query("categories[any] = %s")
Page<Book> findByCategory(String category, Pageable pageable);
```

I get the below exception:
*java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hazelcast.map.impl.query.QueryResultCollection incompatible with org.springframework.data.domain.Page*

As an alternative, I've tried just using a derived query method like:

```java
Page<Book> findByCategories(String category, Pageable pageable);
```

But that throws this exception:
*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot use EqualPredicate predicate with an array or a collection attribute*

Is there a way to combine searching within a list property and returning a Page result with HazelcastRepository?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can use `@Query` with `Page<>` in Hazelcast. However, your second example (`Page<Book> findByCategories(String category, Pageable pageable);`) should work correctly.

To get it working, please check samples in the tests:

- [QueryIT](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/hazelcast/repository/query/QueryIT.java)
- [PagingSortingIT](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/hazelcast/repository/PagingSortingIT.java)
- [SimpleHazelcastRepositoryIT](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/hazelcast/repository/support/SimpleHazelcastRepositoryIT.java)

Comment: Thanks @Rafał Leszko. The domain classes in those tests (https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast/tree/master/src/test/java/test/utils/domain), don't seem to have a list property. The derived queries with Page return type work fine with a non-collection field based query like Book's author. The issue I'm having is when I query on a collection field, like Book categories. I get an exception saying "Cannot use EqualPredicate predicate with an array or a collection attribute"